# how to modify private members that are const?

Tags: c++, vector, constants, mutable

I know this sounds like a strange question, but bear with me.

I have a custom class that has some large objects which need to be returned by reference to avoid a copy.

My class looks something like this:

```
    class csv_File {
    public:
      csv_File(std::string); //constructor
      std::string const& access(int,int) const;
      void modify_element(int column,int row ,std::string value) {
        storage.at(row).at(column)=value;
    }

    private:
      mutable std::vector < std::vector<std::string> > storage;

    };
```

The code for access is:

```
    string const& csv_File::access(int column,int row) const {
    return storage.at(row).at(column);
    }
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error, as it wants

```
csv_File::modify_element(int column,int row ,std::string value) const {}
```

In practice, storage is logically const, but I just need to be able to modify it once in a while.  Is there a way to do this?

Also, a related question.  If I call modify_element to modify an element in storage, but previously, I have returned a reference to that element using access, will the reference that was returned previously pick up the new value after the modify_element call?

Comment: What exactly needs the `modify_element` call? I don't see anything calling it.

Comment: What's the **exact** error message you get?

Comment: And, what's the definition of `data_store`? Please cut-and-paste the precise program that demonstrates the problem, not something that is almost like it. For a description of how to produce minimal complete samples, and why it is important, please see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: It seems like somewhere you call modify_element on a const csv_File.

Comment: When I tried to compile your program, I got several errors as well, none of them related to your question. After fixing the errors, I got this program: http://ideone.com/GYyNs, which compiles with no errors. Could you restate your question?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the class definition, which often produces odd errors.

Comment: Hi everybody, sorry about the poorly written question, I should have done a direct copy/paste instead of rewriting it on the fly. There were a couple mistakes as pointed out above, the missing semi colon and the data_store should actually be storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing up your program, and with the hint from @user763305, I suppose you have something like this (note: this program compiles, but invokes undefined behavior when run, since the `storage` vector is left empty):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class csv_File {
public:
  csv_File(std::string) {}
  std::string const& access(int,int) const;
  void modify_element(int column,int row ,std::string value) {
    storage.at(row).at(column)=value;
  }

private:
  mutable std::vector < std::vector<std::string> > storage;

};

std::string const& csv_File::access(int column,int row) const {
  return storage.at(row).at(column);
}

const csv_File& Factory() { static csv_File foo("foo.txt"); return foo; }
int main(){
    const csv_File& f(Factory());
    f.modify_element(1, 2, "hello");
}
```

and you get an error like this:

```
cs.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
cs.cc:24: error: passing ‘const csv_File’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void csv_File::modify_element(int, int, std::string)’ discards qualifiers
```

So, you have a `const` object and are trying to invoke `modify_element` on it. Logically, this is a mistake -- you can't modify `const` objects!

You have, as I see it, two choices for a fix. Either you can declare the `vector` object `mutable` and the `modify_element` method `const`, or you can modify your object factory to return non-const references.

Solution 1:

```
...
  void modify_element(int column,int row ,std::string value) const {
    storage.at(row).at(column)=value;
  }
...
```

Solution 2:

```
...
const csv_File& Factory() { static csv_File foo("foo.txt"); return foo; }
csv_File& RW_Factory() { static csv_File foo("foo.txt"); return foo; }
...
  const csv_File& f(RW_Factory());
...
```

---

***EDIT***
And, yes, if you previously returned a reference to a `string` in your `vector`, and you subsequently assign a new value to that `string` as you do in `modify_element`, then the previous reference will reflect the new value.

Note that the previous reference will be invalid if you destroy the vector, erase that `vector` element, or do anything to cause the `vector` to grow beyond its previous capacity.

Comment: Aside: `modify_element` really should takes its third parameter by reference, not by value: `const std::string& value`.

Comment: Thanks, for taking the time to figure out my incomplete code.  The first solution provided essentially does what I am looking for.  Can you give some more information why the reference becomes invalid of the vector grows?

Comment: When a `vector` grows, if it grows beyond the capacity of its memory region, it must be copied into a new, larger memory region; the old now-too-small region is destroyed. Thus, any pointer (or reference or iterator) pointing into the old, now discarded memory is invalid. From the C++03 standard, §23.2.4.3, ¶1: "[vector::insert] causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity", and §23.2.4.2, ¶5: "Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the sequence."